# Why is the output like that?

Tags: c, string, pointers, recursion, stack

I have to analyze this code and I really don't understand how it prints things over than " ! ".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f(int i, int *v, char* p){
    int x;
    if(strlen(p)>0){
        x=f(++i,v,++p);
        printf("%c", *(--p)-*(v+(--i)));
    }else
    printf("! ");
    return x;
}

int main(){
    int v[4]={3,1,2,4}, a=3124;
    char k[5]="HOGF";
    char *p=k;
    a=f(0,v,p);
    return 0;
    
}
```

The expected output is

! BENE

Why doesn't the function stop at " ! "?

Comment: did you executed that code in a debugger to follow step by step the executions ?

Comment: Hi, yes. I did run the code and I decided to print x both in the if condition and after the else. What I got was a bunch of adresses as expected. Beside that, I can't really process the algorithm behind the recursion within the if condition.

Comment: the value return by *f* is undefined because it is the 'value' of the non initialized variable *x*, but that value is never 'really' used

Comment: The return value of `f` is undefined.  The only time `x` is set is when `f` calls itself, and when it finally doesn't call itself, `x` is never set.  So the return value can be anything.  It's undefined behavior.  It's a bug.

Comment: `Why doesn't the function stop at " ! "` because the code progress in the string "HOGF" up to reach the ending null character and in that case `strlen` is 0 which is not `>0` so "! " is print, then the recursive calls are 'poped ' producing the print of the other characters

Comment: Sorry, but when the *p finally reaches '\0' (and therefore strlen(p)=0, so it is not >0) and the else condition is executed, doesn't the function close? Does the " return x " affect the recursion at the end?

Comment: the return does not really matter, I tried making it void and the issue is still there: https://onlinegdb.com/HJlB5IqiRU

Comment: yes the return value does not matter

Comment: Ok, so what really does matter are the pointers to the string. The printf  `printf("%c", *(--p)-*(v+(--i))) ` is going on because ... ? Also, maybe I did not point out this well: the expected output is "! BENE" so it's ok with it, just the algorithm is pretty difficult for me to understand.

Comment: do you understand my answer ?

Comment: Sure, I do! thank a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see a problem with the above output.
In the code you have provided, the function ' f ' is being called recursively, meaning you are calling the function within itself.
When the statement `a=f(0,v,p)` is executed the execution context switches from the main function to the f function.

```
(strlen(p)>0)
```

this condition is satisfied at this point as p refers to "HOGF" and its length is greater than 0. Therefore the if block is executed and not the else block
Now in the if block, `x=f(++i,v,++p)` gets executed and this is what a recursive function call is. While you are still in the context of function f  ,you invoke it again.
This adds a new execution context into your call stack  and since ++p is passed, instead of "HOGF", as the pointer is incremented to the next address, "OGF" gets passed.
This addition to the stack will happen until the a return statement is encountered.
That is 5 different functions are stacked on top of the main function. A function below cannot continue to execute unless the one above it returns and is popped out.
In this case "OGF"  ->  "GF"  ->  "F"  ->  "" are the values that get passed to the function such that the topmost function receives an empty string as its parameter
At this point when an empty string gets passed as an argument to the f function, `(strlen(p)>0)` will evaluate to false and the else block will be executed for the first time.Thus printing "! " as the first thing in the output.
You ask why execution wont stop here.
Because we have build a stack of function f , and after printing "! " the function is not over until it reaches return. When return statement is encountered. This will pop the topmost f function in our stack and return the value of 'x' in the topmost f function.
The value of 'x' will be a junk value as x is a *non-initialized variable*.

```
x=f(++i,v,++p);
```

means that the value of x from the topmost f function will be passed as value to the x in the f function right below it in the execution stack. At this context the function still has `printf("%c", *(--p)-*(v+(--i)))` and the return statement to execute.
`*(--p)-*(v+(--i))` is responsible for subtracting from the characters in "HOGF" and printing "BENE" instead,
For example `--p` returns the pointer to 'F' and `--i` decrements i to 3 , therefore
'F'- v[3] becomes 'F' - 4  which is 'B'
After printing 'B' the function returns the value of 'x' to the next function in the execution stack. Similarly 'E','N','E' are also printed and finally the function returns the value of 'x' to the main function where function 'f' was initially called.

Interestingly the value of 'x', though not 0 always, will be the same in every context of f function and it will be equal to the value passed by the topmost f function that is responsible for printing "! ". You can understand this by observation and understanding recursion in a better way.
Resources to consider:
Recursion and call-stack: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-recursion-works-explained-with-flowcharts-and-a-video-de61f40cb7f9/ 
How *(v+(--i)) became v[--i ] : [https://www.prismnet.com/~mcmahon/Notes/arrays_and_pointers.html](https://www.prismnet.com/%7Emcmahon/Notes/arrays_and_pointers.html) 
If this doesn't clear your doubt feel free to comment.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer! >`after printing "! " the function is not over until it reaches return. When return statement is encountered. This will pop the topmost f function in our stack and return the value of 'x' in the topmost f function.` This was the critical point to me, because I really didn't get how it got past the if condtion, and you gave an excellent explanation! Also, the sources will be very precious as I have to draw the stacks and the variables running into this type function. Again, thanks a lot, this couldn't be any clearer. :)

Comment: No problem mate !! It would be great if you could upvote my answer. I'm new on SO and this could be the first upvote I get !! :) Happy coding

Comment: lol you still do not have UV on answer because @demagorgico accepted your answer rather than to UV it, and doing that unaccepted my answer (only one answer can be accepted by question)

Comment: I'm really new to answering on SO, thank you so much for helping me understand !! @bruno . Also initially he hadn't accepted my answer or UV, so that's why I asked

Comment: @KevinTony there is no problem at all, happy coding / SO ^^

Comment: @KevinTony I did both upvoting and pin your answer as soon as you commented, but since I have not 15 reputation points ( I guess), my upvote is not displayed. I'm new as well so Iidk if I'm missing something :)

Comment: @demagorgico No problem ! Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

The value return by *f* is undefined because it is the 'value' of the non initialized variable *x*, but that value is never 'really' used.

> `Why doesn't the function stop at " ! "`

Because the code progress in the string "HOGF" up to reach the ending null character and in that case `strlen` is 0 which is obviously not `>0` so "! " is print, then the recursive calls are 'poped ' producing the print of the other characters.

In detail :

- at the first execution of *f* from *main* the variable *p* points to "HOGF" and *i* values 0, the string is not empty, so recursive call
- the 2 times *p* points to "OGF" and *i* values 1, the string is not empty, so recursive call
- the 3 times *p* points to "GF" and *i* values 2, the string is not empty, so recursive call
- the 4 times *p* points to "F" and *i* values 3, the string is not empty, so recursive call
- the 5 times *p* point to "" and *i* values 4, `strlen(p)>0`is false so "! " is print
- back to the 4 execution of *f*, the two `--` cancel the `++` in the recursive call arguments for *p* and *i*, so *p* points to F and *i* values 3, `v[3]` is 4 so that print the character 'F' - 4 being 'B'
- back to the 3 execution of *f*, the two `--` cancel the `++` in the recursive call arguments for *p* and *i*, so *p* points to G and *i* values 2, `v[2]` is 2 so that print the character 'G' - 2 being 'E'
- back to the 2 execution of *f*, the two `--` cancel the `++` in the recursive call arguments for *p* and *i*, so *p* points to O and *i* values 1, `v[1]` is 1 so that print the character 'O' - 1 being 'N'
- back to the first execution of *f*, the two `--` cancel the `++` in the recursive call arguments for *p* and *i*, so *p* points to H and *i* values 0, `v[0]` is 3 so that print the character 'H' - 3 being 'E'

So the program prints `! BENE`

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I undertood perfectly!! Thanks again for your time! :)